# Export object id in DXF from Inkscape

Tags: dxf, inkscape

I have to integrate Inkscape drawings into QGIS. In order to do so, I export the drawings in DXF format from Inkscape. There's no problem to georeference them in QGIS, but I would like to know if there is a way to export path ids from Inkscape? That would enable me to reconstruct properly geometries (that is, create polygons) with this attribute, since the export create a bunch of lines for each closed object ("path") from Inkscape. The `st_node`/`st_polygonise` in Postgis can't work for me, since my objects are overlapping, and polygons are created for each intersection.

Comment: BetterBetterDXF Inkscape Extension > You need to ungroup everything and convert all objects to paths first. https://github.com/Fab-Lab-Fabulous-St-Pauli-Hamburg-DE/InkscapeExtension_BetterBetterDXFOutput2021#readme

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this.

Comment: I have tested this extension but I didn't get the path number...